# How can I invoke a desktop app from Google Cloud Platform services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, architecture, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm building a desktop client app (win/linux/mac) with a backend hosted in GCP (I'm considering other cloud platforms too). The desktop app should be minimalistic and provide access to local machine resources to the backend. And I'm looking for a way to invoke my app from the server (when some event occurs) and then the app would do some work on a local machine. Here's what I've tried so far.

1. [Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries). Seems like it does what I need, but to make it work I have to create a service account, generate JSON key and store it locally, which is not good. I can restrict the service account access permissions, of course, but still it doesn't look good to me. Maybe there are other ways to auth my app running at the end user machine? I want to keep my desktop app minimal (ideally without UI, just an "agent" console process / Windows service). Maybe I could consider a login screen to connect the app with the backend, if that solves the problem, but I don't want to overcomplicate.
2. [Google Cloud Run + SignalR / WebSockets](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets). This solution also looks good, but it has one significant disadvantage. As long as there's at least one open WebSocket the Cloud Run instance is considered active and therefore billed. There are [other difficulties](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets#multiple-instances) related to scalability and container instances synchronization too.

What do you think about the options above, and what are the other possibilities? Am I left with REST API and polling for updates? I'm quite new to the cloud stuff so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to invoke your local app from Google Cloud, you need 2 things

- The first one, to register your app on Google Cloud, with, preferably, a auth mecanism (can be an API key for example). Like this, the GCP backend know where to call you app (which IP/port) and how (the auth mechanism)
- The second is to have your app up and running and listen external communication. HTTP is the easiest way. Wait a HTTP call on the IP/port defined during the registration, check the auth and perform the process.

You can store the data (location and the auth) in firestore for example, and use Cloud Run to perform the HTTP call.

---

You can also inverse the solution and to poll (long polling or regular poll) the backend from the local app when it is running.

The 2 approach are possible, the second one slightly easier but can be challenging to manage the security.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Your solution makes sense, but the problem is that the client app is going to be installed on end-user machines which are (almost) always behind the NAT. That's why I was looking for a ready-to-use solution that handles this (like i.e. Pub/Sub does). If I don't find a simple way to auth my app I would probably go with the polling solution...

Comment: PubSub has 2 mode. If you use PUSH mode, you need to know the IP/url of your target. And behind a NAT, it's indeed a problem (with PUbSub or any other Push (from the cloud) solution to your app. The second mode is Pull: The app create a connexion and listen the subscription. It's a polling solution, more packaged that other, but it's not magic, it's polling also! The challenge here is the authentication. According with the flow (with users or not) different solutions are possible.